# pjax with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, pjax

I am using rack-pjax gem as described in the railscasts  [playing with pjax](http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax?view=comments)

But the issue i am having with my layout is, i have some dynamic generated links and page headings on top of the main 'yield' call in the application layout. Those links will be generated dynamically based the main yield. Though i am putting the dynamically loaded part in the data-pjax-container, that part is still not coming(being invisible). I guess that is because of the way pjax works, when ever a pjax request goes to the server, it will carry a 'X-PJAX' header and the server doesn't load the whole layout if it finds the X-PJAX in the headers.

```
%div{:id = "content", :data => {"pjax-container" => true}}

  #context_menu
    = THE DYNAMICALLY GENERATED CONTENT GOES HERE
    .clear

  #pageHeading
    #breadcrumbs
      = THE DYNAMICALLY GENERATED CONTENT GOES HERE
      .clear


    .bodytext
      = yield   / THIS IS THE MAIN YIELD
    .clear
```

Any suggestions to get around this please..

Answer (score 0):

You can work around it by explicitly telling rails what links should make a pjax call in your views instead of using the implicit pjax header , For instance:

```
<%= link_to 'user', user_path, :'data-pjax' => '#id_of_target_pjax_container' %>
```